# The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, server

When I'm using PUT or DELETE method it shows that error.
I think I have a right configuration in `web.config`:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Did I miss something?
The response from server catched by fiddler is 405,

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}
```

Comment: Try calling it from Fiddler or RestClient? Let's see if it works from there

Comment: @Shahbaz, using api debug tool showing it work well with put, but my tool didn't send a options request. i think that is the problem

Comment: Options request is usually sent when a preflight request is made for CORS. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

Comment: @Shahbaz, thats one situation, when sending a put or delete http request which is not simple http request will send a options request first to ask if the server can handle this method. But my problem is my server can handle put and delete request but cant handle options, that struggle.

Comment: Hi Loic - did you ever find a solution for this question? I'm having the same issue.